# Wordpress Issue with Health Check up Results

Tags: wordpress

I am getting this error:

> A plugin has prevented updates by disabling wp_version_check()

This is preventing my Home Page from changing the themes and letting the latest post appear the first.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many reasons for this error to appear in the WP proceed with the following method

1. Disable all plugins and activate the plugins one and check which plugin is causing the problem
2. Revert to the default Wordpress theme
3. Check for the `.htaccess` & `functions.php` file if any code is added or any snippet is added if yes remove them
4. Enable debug in `wp-config.php` files
5. Disable CDN like cloudflare temporiarly
6. Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ and Troubleshoot your site
7. Contact your host for your additional support

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Child Theme check functions.php for errors.

In my Child Theme functions.php the last closing tag `?>` had a space after it. Therefore, I deleted the space and saved functions.php.

Deleting the space solved the error

> A plugin has prevented updates by disabling wp_version_check()

Also, you could try deleting the last closing tag `?>`

Comment: there is not even a `?>` at the end of the functions.php file